# Multiple dropdowns from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make multiple dropdowns from data out of my `mysql` database. I want 4 dropdowns to be exact. This is what I have at this moment:

```
<?php

mysql_connect('#', '#', '#');
mysql_select_db('test');

$sql = "SELECT wie, waar, metwie, voeruig FROM data";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='test'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<option value='" . $row['wie'] . "'>" . $row['wie'] . "</option>";

}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Comment: Avoid using _deprecated_ mysql functions. Ps. _I want to make multiple dropdowns_ did you mean dependent dropboxes?

Comment: So what's the problem exactly ?

Comment: There is only one dropdown there with multiple options

Comment: yes four separately with own column

Comment: @ M.S.P Now I have 1 dropdown and 1 want 4 of them

Comment: @SebastiaanNolte If the 4 dropboxes are dependent then you got to dig deeper than _just_ this. A proper relations with the tables in your db along with using probably AJAX to fill in the dependent dropbox.

Comment: I wish @Fred-ii- was here to see the answers being posted. `:3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instance, this:

```
mysql_connect('#', '#', '#');
mysql_select_db('test');

$sql = "SELECT wie FROM data";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<select name='test1'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<option value='" . $row['wie'] . "'>" . $row['wie'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

$sql = "SELECT waar FROM data";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<select name='test1'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<option value='" . $row['waar'] . "'>" . $row['waar'] . "</option>";
 }
 echo "</select>";

$sql = "SELECT metwie FROM data";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<select name='test2'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<option value='" . $row['metwie'] . "'>" . $row['metwie'] . "</option>";
 }
 echo "</select>";

$sql = "SELECT voeruig FROM data";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<select name='test3'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<option value='" . $row['voeruig'] . "'>" . $row['voeruig'] . "</option>";
 }
 echo "</select>";
?>
```

Comment: Please avoid using _deprecated_ mysql functions and also write abit about why/how this answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by HawasKaPujaari, avoid using mysql. Use `mysqli`. You could use a conditional switch statement like this:

```
        <?php
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "test");

        /* check connection */
        if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
            exit();
        }


        /* Select queries return a resultset */
        if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT wie, waar, metwie, voeruig FROM data")) {

            printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", $result->num_rows);

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            switch ($row) {
            case "wie":
                echo "<select name='wie'>";
                echo "<option value='" . $row['wie'] . "'>" . $row['wie'] . "</option>";
                echo "</select>";
                break;
            case "waar":
                echo "<select name='waar'>";
                echo "<option value='" . $row['waar'] . "'>" . $row['waar'] . "</option>";
                echo "</select>";
                break;
            case "metwie":
                echo "<select name='metwie'>";
                echo "<option value='" . $row['metwie'] . "'>" . $row['metwie'] . "</option>";
                echo "</select>";
                break;
            }
            case "voeruig":
                echo "<select name='voeruig'>";
                echo "<option value='" . $row['voeruig'] . "'>" . $row['voeruig'] . "</option>";
                echo "</select>";
                break;
            }

        /* free result set */
        $result->close();
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Try replacing each

case "text": 

with 

case $row['text']:

Answer (score 0):

php and mysql are different softwares. what you are doing here is connecting php with `mysql` using `mysql_*()` functions
in your case what you get is an array in php. you can use this array for whatever you want. if you want to print array as is as for debugging use:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($row);
echo "</pre>";
```

From this you will get array structure
then you ca use different dropdowns for array elements

Note: `mysql_*()` is not safe. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 0):

Try code below. hope it help you

```html
<?php
$wie=array();
$waar =array();
$metwie =array();
$voeruig =array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$wie[]=$row["wie"];
$waar[]=$row["waar"];
$metwie[]=$row["metwie"];
$voeruig[]=$row["voeruig"];

}
?> 
<select name="wie">
<?php
foreach($wie as $k=>$v)
{
?>
<option value="<?php echo $v?>"><?php echo $v;?>
<php 

}
?>
</option>
<select name="waar">
<?php
foreach($waar as $k=>$v)
{
?>
<option value="<?php echo $v?>"><?php echo $v;?> </option>
<php 

}
?>
</select>
<select name="metwie">
<?php
foreach($metwie as $k=>$v)
{
?>
<option value="<?php echo $v?>"><?php echo $v;?></option>
<php 

}
?>
</select>
<select name="voeruig">
<?php
foreach($voeruig as $k=>$v)
{
?>
<option value="<?php echo $v?>"><?php echo $v;?> </option>
<php 

}
?>
</select>
```